# Custom view groups in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm currently trying to learn about the various ways you can create custom Views and Viewgroups in Android. There seems to be a few videos by Huyen Tue Dao explaining the basic concepts as well as some old code on GitHub and SO that doesn't have much explanation or documentation. What are the basic things to consider when overriding OnLayout and OnMeasure?

An area of confusion is the MeasureChildWithMargins() method. There doesn't seem to be a consistent rule or heuristic when passing in width_used or height_used into the argument parameters. First of all why would you pass these as an argument and secondly, if you had multiple children apart of the view. Would all of these children increment the height and width used?

Comment: you are just using android studio to develop your app, but it actually makes no difference to your code or your question, so you only have to mention android studio when you're asking about a specific feature of the IDE itself

Comment: what specifically do you want to know, are you having any problems or any additional details you can add to your question ? perhaps nothing has changed since those videos you saw